# Github like dynamic routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What would be the best way to implement routes like github uses?

Ex:

```
github.com/about
github.com/37signals
github.com/javan
```

I'm guessing /about is a real controller, but the second and third probably load a user controller. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a route like `match '/:id/' => 'user#show'` for a user like `javan` and have the `show` action in the `user` controller look up the user by username.

So in the user controller:

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

You can learn more about routes [here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)